# Mongoose Sort by elements in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have my docs like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Valerio",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Samad",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": ["1", "3", "4"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "Ayub",
    "gender": "F",
    "favorites": ["1", "4"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "name": "Apour",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": ["2"]
  }
]
```

and I want to sort them based on _id : "1" exists in the favorites array like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Samad",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": ["1", "3", "4"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "Ayub",
    "gender": "F",
    "favorites": ["1", "4"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "name": "Apour",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": ["2"]
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Valerio",
    "gender": "M",
    "favorites": []
  }
]
```

here is what I'm using but this is not sorting it's just filtering :

```
User.find({
    $and: [
        { favorites: { $all: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId("1")] } },
        { gender: { $in:['M'] } },
      ],
  })
```

i would really appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a temporary key that holds `1` if the key exists
and `0` if the key doesn't exist, sort in descending order based on this temporary key.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "searchElemExists": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$in": [
              "1",  // <-- Value you want to be sorted based on existance
              "$favorites"
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "searchElemExists": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "searchElemExists": 0,
    },
  },
])
```

[Playground Execution of Sample Data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3EwWlG8lBKU)

Comment: Amazing it works thank you so much. if I wanted to sort by *_id* and *gender* also what do you recommend ?

Comment: Add the required sorts in `$sort` stage and you should be good to go